# Late binding for const attributes in C++ classes?

Tags: c++, oop, class

I know there is no late binding for class attributes. But i need a good pattern to do this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    const int i;
    B() : i(1) {}
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    const int i;
    D() : i(2) {}
};


int main()
{
    D d;
    B *ptr = &d;

    cout << ptr->i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is `1`, but I expected `2`. I guess, i should use a different pattern. Any suggestion?

Comment: You would need to do something at runtime, like a map<string,int>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of `i` that gets output is dependent on the *compile-time* type definition. You've defined two different variables, so you'll get two different results. The way to fix this is to make sure there's only one version of the variable. You can use a contructor in B to initialize the const variable.

```
class B
{
public:
    const int i;
    B() : i(1) {}
protected:
    B(int j) : i(j) {}
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    D() : B(2) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a virtual method, just like all late binding in C++.

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual int get_i() const { return 1; }
};

class D : public B
{
public:
    virtual int get_i() const { return 2; }
};
```

Comment: I use this pattern usually, but is there any better pattern without virtual functions?

Comment: @MasoudM.: No. This is _the_ pattern. Why are you afraid of it?

Comment: You know, I thought your idea was the right one too when I read the question, then I read the accepted answer and hit myself over the head (metaphorically speaking) and said "Doh!".

Comment: @Omnifarious: While the accepted answer tackles the exact problem at hand, it does not deal with the title of the question, that is, it does not produce late-binding, but rather produce a workaround for the case where the value is independent of the type of the most derived object (in the general sense, that is, it will always access `B::i`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: This is true, but in the case of a constant class member, the accepted answer is is a much better solution than late binding. The value won't change after the class is constructed. There is no need for late binding. People often don't ask the right questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the data members `B::i` (initialized to 1) and `D::i` (initialized to 2).  They aren't the same, and calls through a `B *` will get `B::i`, not `D::i`.

In order to get polymorphic behavior, you'll need to use `virtual` functions.  (Another approach is in Mark Ransom's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You're just adding new members to the derived class, which also happen to *hide* the members of the base class. That's not what you want. Instead, use a virtual function:

```
class B
{
  int m_i;
public:
  virtual ~B() { }
  virtual int get() const { return m_i; }
};

class D : public B
{
  int m_j;
public:
  virtual int get() const { return m_j; }
};
```

Usage:

```
D d;
B & b = d;
std::cout << b.get() << std::endl;  // correct dynamic dispatch
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtual dispatch works on function members, but not data members.

If you desperately need the same-named variable in both classes, then you can use an accessor function to do the job:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class B
{
    const int i;
public:
    B() : i(1) {}
    virtual int getI() { return i; }
};

class D : public B
{
    const int i;
public:
    D() : i(2) {}
    virtual int getI() { return i; }
};


int main()
{
    D d;
    B* ptr = &d;

    cout << ptr->getI() << endl;
}

// Output: 2
```

#### [Live demo.](http://www.ideone.com/RqC0M)

Comment: But it needs repeating `virtual int getI() { return i; }` in all child classes!

Comment: @MasoudM.: Correct. And, actually, this is a _good_ thing. When the behaviour changes slightly for one of the derived classes, you are readily available to implement that.